# How to (effectively) make a group an owner for changing privileges

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, chmod, chown

I have data on disk which has a high likely-hood of accidentally being modified and I want to remove all write privileges by myself or anyone else. However, occasionally this data DOES need to be modified by me or someone on the team.

If I'm the owner and there are only read privileges, I am the only person on the team able to change the privileges of the data so that someone else can write. What I'd like is that the data was nominally read only, but anyone on the team could change the privileges so they can make a change.

The only solution I could think of was essentially assigning some user 'sudo' privileges for `chmod`, but the probability of that happening in my org is essentially 0.

Comment: Could you use SELinux or have the partition (or a loopback device or unionmount) abstract or obfusicate this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not completely familiar with some of your suggestions, but I think the answer would be 'No'. I'm limited to using the existing infrastructure. I was hoping there was some usage of 'chown'/'chmod' or something else I wasn't familiar with that would help

Comment: Using chown to do what you are asking without sudo or equivalent privs is not possible. SELinux can almost certainly help you... But only if its turned on. The other ideas I floated were "out the box hacks" - which will likely be required to implement this if you font go down the selinux/ sudo path.